# Big O algorithms minimum time

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I know that for some problems, no matter what algorithm you use to solve it, there will always be a certain minimum amount of time that will be required to solve the problem.  I know BigO captures the worst-case (maximum time needed), but how can you find the minimum time required as a function of n? Can we find the minimum time needed for sorting n integers, or perhaps maybe finding the minimum of n integers?

Comment: Is the Minimum amount of time that might be needed for sorting n integers linear? i.e., O(n) in case of already sorted either in ascending or descending. Also is the minimum amount of time that might be needed for finding the minimum of n integers linear? i.e., O(n) in any case it’s the minimum.

Comment: Minimum time to sort n integer(which is the best case) means that your n number is already sorted. Since you number is already sorted algo will take minimum time, whereas Worst-Case is when you all n number need the sorting.

Comment: thank you! but im still a little fuzzy, how does that go back with finding the minimum time finding needed for sorting n integers?

Comment: To sort n integer we will apply a loop and do the comparison of current  item with rest of the items. If you n integer is already sorted than comparison is less. Here is the link to various sorting algo http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: Do you mean big-Omega notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are looking for is called `best case complexity`. It is kind of useless analysis for algorithms while worst case analysis is the most important analysis and average case analysis is sometimes used in special scenario.

the best case complexity depends on the algorithms. for example in a linear search the best case is, when the searched number is at the beginning of the array. or in a binary search it is in the first dividing point. in these cases the complexity is O(1).

for a single problem, best case complexity may vary depending on the algorithm. for example lest discuss about some basic sorting algorithms.

1. in bubble sort best case is when the array is already sorted. but even in this case you have to check all element to be sure. so the best case here is O(n). same goes to the insertion sort
2. for quicksort/mergesort/heapsort the best case complexity is O(n log n)
3. for selection sort it is O(n^2)

So from the above case you can understand that the complexity ( whether it is best , worst or average) depends on the algorithm, not on the problem

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think i got it now(:

Comment: thanks @Luke12. if you think the answer was helpful you can upvote/accept the answer .. and welcome to the SO :)

Comment: Well, the best case (i.e. the worst case behavior of the best algorithm) for problems makes sense as well if you fix the type of the computing device. For example, for minimum search you have to look at each number so you get a minimum of Omega(n); similarly for sorting algorithms that work by comparing two elements the minimum is Omega(n log n).

Comment: yes I accepted your answer! I just wish I could upvote (not enough experience yet)